# <picture> src (active source)

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to retrieve a `<picture>` element's currently used source in javascript without using the viewport width / pixel density?

Something similar to `<select>:selected`

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/minlare/s6xu5z6o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<picture>` element is still experimental so I do not think there is an API to get the "active" source  yet. I did however find the following issues for the `<picture>` spec expecting the element to have a `currentSrc` element.

https://github.com/ResponsiveImagesCG/picture-element/issues/223

`currentSrc` is the behaviour I also would have expected but currently it is simply not implemented in Chrome or FireFox.

Comment: While `currentSrc` does give you the selected url - resolved to absolute form - it does not give you the actual `<source>` element that provided that url; this latter problem is what the OP's asking about - and is what I'd like to learn too.

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you're using jQuery:

```
$('img').on('load', function() {
   console.log($(this)[0].currentSrc);
})
```

Comment: While that does give you the selected url - resolved to absolute form - it does not give you the actual `<source>` element that provided that url; this latter problem is what the OP's asking about - and is what I'd like to know too.